# How to place object in specicifc place with tiled and AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine, tile

I am using AndEngine to create a Test run project.

I am doing well so far. The only problem i run into is when using Tiled map editor and i load the tmx. file into the project. The map is loaded correctly, but i am having trouble understanding how the whole tile piece works. How would you go about positioning a Charactor or a object on a specific area of the map like if you have a grown how do you set place the object on the top of the ground for a side scroller type game?

And also is there collision detection so if the character is on the ground then it does something?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this example my friend, it will help you
[Andengine tutorial and example](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/collision-objects-from-tmx-map-t3907.html)